# XS.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xce00080, needed 0xdb80080)

Tags: perl

I was using perl5 and executing my script

```
perl myscript.R
```

and was getting following error.

```
Can't locate local/lib.pm in @INC (you may need to install the local::lib module) (@INC contains: /kb/deployment/lib /kb/deployment/lib/perl5 /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.24.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl5/5.24 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl/5.24 /usr/share/perl/5.24 /usr/local/lib/site_perl /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/perl-base).
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

so i installed local::lib using following command

```
cpan local::lib
```

but after i tried to use the perl myscript.pl and getting

```
  XS.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xce00080, needed 0xdb80080)
```

I am clueless about fixing thsi issue.

Comment: Probably you compiled some module used  by `myscript.R` using a different `perl` version than the one you use currently. The solution is then to recompile the modules with the current version of `perl`. Please give more details about the script `myscript.R`

Answer (score 10):

The version of the binary component and the version of the Perl component of the module you are trying to load don't match.

You appear to have used local::lib to install modules in your home dir. Upgrading your `perl` causes this setup to fail badly. The solution is to delete `~/perl5`<sup>[1]</sup> and reinstall the modules you had locally installed.

---

What if you have more than one build of Perl or you don't want to have this problem the next time you upgrade Perl?

There are ways of telling the installers to install modules in your home dir in such a way that multiple builds of Perl can share the installation directory,<sup>[2]</sup> but it doesn't really work.<sup>[3]</sup>

This is why I use [`perlbrew`](https://perlbrew.pl/) to install Perl itself in my home dir so I don't have to override the installation location of modules. Using `perlbrew` has the following benefits:

- You can have multiple builds of Perl installed without hassle.
- You can upgrade Perl when you want to, independent of OS updates.
- You can test scripts and modules with newer versions of Perl before switching to using it "permanently".
- You can test scripts and modules with older versions of Perl.

---

1. Well, rename it until you're sure you're done with it.
2. By passing the `PREFIX`/`--prefix` and `LIB`/`--lib` options to `Makefile.PL`/`Build.PL` instead of `INSTALL_BASE`/`--install-base`.
3. You get into problems when a pure-Perl module depends on an XS module.