# makeinfo: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched

Tags: perl, shared-libraries, ubuntu-22.04, binutils

I recently upgraded Ubuntu on my system to version 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish) which broke my cross-compiler toolchain, which consists of binutils and gcc configured for the i686 architecture.

Running `makeinfo` post OS upgrade gives

```
parsetexi/Parsetexi.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xcd00080, needed 0xeb00080)
```

My understanding of the error message is that the loadable lib Parsetexi depends on the version of Perl I had installed prior to the OS upgrade, and the newer version is not backwards compatible causing the error. So the solution seems to be to rebuild the perl shared library Parsetexi.so to use the newer version of perl.

So I looked at the `/usr/lib/texinfo` directory and ran `ldd Parsetexi.so` which gave

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff9965a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fbd21cbb000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fbd21f2d000)
```

No mention of Perl...

If I look at `/usr/share/texinfo/Texinfo/XS` there is a `parsetexi` directory containing the file `Parsetexi.pm`. It is part of the `Texinfo::Parser` package. Looking at [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69486810/5393006), maybe I just need to upgrade the package using cpan. I tried `cpan upgrade /(.*)/` but it did not fix the issue.

I have looked at info on [Texinfo](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/9.1-systemd/chapter06/texinfo.html) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61003436/xs-c-loadable-library-and-perl-binaries-are-mismatched-got-handshake-key-0xce0) but still am not sure how to proceed. Any help appreciated.

Edit: I have since re-downloaded Texinfo (which contains makeinfo) [from here](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/texinfo/), and followed the [installation steps here](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/9.1-systemd/chapter06/texinfo.html). After install, I ran `makeinfo` but still get the same binary mismatch.

Edit 2: I have now cleaned up my machine such that running `which -a makeinfo` yields only one installation at `/usr/local/bin/makeinfo`.

Not sure if this is relevant, but I was able to find two files titled `Parsetexi.pm`, one at `/usr/local/share/texinfo/Texinfo/XS/parsetexi/Parsetexi.pm` and the other at `/usr/share/perl5/Texinfo/XS/parsetexi/Parsetexi.pm`. Both of which have as second line `use 5.00405` which differs from my perl at `/bin/perl` which has version v5.34.0.

For @HåkonHægland, I am not sure how to make use of your last comment about line 165 or 171 in `XSLoader.pm`.

Comment: `MAKEINFO doc/bfd.info` : How did you install makeinfo? (seems like it belongs to a texinfo package: https://stackoverflow.com/a/338384/2173773) Maybe you need to recompile texinfo with a newer version of perl?

Comment: *"I also looked at the /usr/lib/texinfo directory and ran ldd Parsetexi.so"* : Did you also try `ldd` on the makeinfo command?

Comment: @HåkonHægland running `makeinfo` from the command line seems to isolate the problem, i.e. I get `parsetexi/Parsetexi.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xcd00080, needed 0xeb00080)`

Comment: Running `sudo apt-get install texinfo` yields `texinfo is already the newest version (6.8-4build1).`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Running `sudo find / -iname "makeinfo"` gives `/usr/bin/makeinfo` and `/usr/local/bin/makeinfo` both of which are symbolic links to `texi2any` which is a perl script text executable, so `ldd` cannot be applied.

Comment: I think I need to uninstall the `Texinfo::Parser` package and reinstall it for the newest version of perl. But I really don't know how to do that.

Comment: *"I think I need to uninstall the Texinfo::Parser"* Isn't this module installed as part of installing the `texinfo` package?

Comment: I am not sure. I don't really know much about Perl.

Comment: I tried to install texinfo 7.0 now like this: `PERL=/home/hakon/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.38.0/bin/perl configure --prefix=/opt/texinfo` then I ran `make` and then `sudo make install`. After installation I checked that it installed the perl module: `file /opt/texinfo/share/texinfo/Texinfo/Parser.pm` and it outputs:
"/opt/texinfo/share/texinfo/Texinfo/Parser.pm: Perl5 module source, ASCII text"

Comment: At `/usr/share/texinfo/Texinfo` I have `Parser.pm` which is version 7.0.3 since it has the line: `our $VERSION = '7.0.3';`. However, when I run `sudo apt-get install texinfo` it says texinfo is version 6.8-4.

Comment: Can you try open the perl script `/usr/bin/texi2any` in a text editor and check the first line. It should specfiy which perl binary it is going to use. Probably `/usr/bin/perl`.

Comment: @HåkonHægland It is using `/usr/bin/perl`.

Comment: And if you run `/usr/bin/texi2any --version` you get the error message "loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched" ?

Comment: It prints the version, no errors...

Comment: Ok.. but the question states *"Running makeinfo post OS upgrade gives loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched"*. Right?

Comment: Running `/usr/bin/texi2any --version` outputs `texi2any (GNU texinfo) 6.8

Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.`, running `makeinfo` outputs `parsetexi/Parsetexi.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xcd00080, needed 0xeb00080)`

Comment: I thought that `makeinfo` was just a symbolic link file pointing to `/usr/bin/texi2any` ? This is then obviously not the case here. What is the output of `which makeinfo` ?

Comment: I agree, however, running`which makeinfo` yields `/usr/local/bin/makeinfo`, running `file /usr/local/bin/makeinfo` I get `/usr/local/bin/makeinfo: symbolic link to texi2any`. Running `realpath /usr/local/bin/makeinfo` gives `/usr/local/bin/texi2any`. Interestingly, when I run `/usr/local/bin/texi2any --version` it prints the version number as mentioned above, but running `/usr/local/bin/texi2any` by itself causes the binary mismatch error.

Comment: Ok it seems like you have two versions of the script texi2any : `/usr/local/bin/texi2any` and `/usr/bin/texi2any`, right? The perl associated with the last we found to be `/usr/bin/perl` what about the first, is that also associated with that same perl?

Comment: I have three versions of texi2any (no idea how that happened). `which -a texi2any` gives `/usr/local/bin/texi2any`, `/usr/bin/texi2any`, `/bin/texi2any`, I vim-ed through all of them, and they all have `#! /usr/bin/perl` on line 1.

Comment: Wow :) 3 hehe seems messed up.. try to also determine how many versions of `Parsetexi.so` you have? Probably one of those shared libraries belong (has been compiled with) to a different perl then

Comment: Yeh, I will try to figure/clean things up on my end. And update my answer later on if I still am stuck. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yeah ...  you are welcome. btw I suspect it is line 165 or 171 in [`XSLoader.pm`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/texinfo.git/tree/tp/Texinfo/XSLoader.pm) that gives the error:  `my $libref = DynaLoader::dl_load_file($dlpath, $flags);`

Comment: Hello @HåkonHægland, I am back after a break, still with the same problem. Please see my updated question if you still feel like helping!

Comment: I think we should avoid long discussion here in the comments, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/95938/216290. We may discuss more on google chat or email if you like?

Comment: Yes that works, my email is tom.codeninja@gmail.com

Comment: Great I sent you a message on chat now